# Vista de Glyphicon Bootstrap

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente a la hora de usar los GlyphIcons de Bootstrap.

En este momento se visualizan de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que se vea de la siguiente forma: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para los que no me entienden lo que quiero es que sea vea así el icono "a mi parecer font-weight o f-w".

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo RUTA;?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo RUTA;?>/css/style.css">
    <script src="<?php echo RUTA;?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo RUTA;?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login BoardRoster</title>
</head>
<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo RUTA; ?>"><img src="<?php echo RUTA; ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Nomina - OldMutual">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="menu" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
          <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El icono que te aparece no es de Glyphicons... ¿Has sobrescrito la clase usando otro icono?

Comment: no la verdad no, lo unico que hice fue poner los CND de CSS Y JS de bootstrap, no he modificado nada, estoy usandolos tal cual vienen.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el HTML completo (incluyendo el `<head>`)?

Comment: [en este fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3R23/1389/) si funciona... estás usando el [archivo css](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css) correcto ?

Comment: si amigo, es que es lo mas extraño, acabo de descargar nuevamente el bootstrap y sigue igual, ya revise lo del cache y no es eso

Comment: has probado añadiendo la linea `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">` ??

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, si funciono, relativamente, lo unico que hice fue a partir de tu comentario busque las CDN de Bootstrap Glyphicons y lo agregue y listo, no use el que me diste ya que parece que ese  CDN esta caido, muchas gracias tu comentario fue util.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si miras [este Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3R23/1389/) verás que funciona.

Tienes que añadir la linea que agrega los estilos de css para Glyphicons quedando asi:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo RUTA;?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo RUTA;?>/css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css‌​/bootstrap-glyphicon‌​s.css">

    <script src="<?php echo RUTA;?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo RUTA;?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login BoardRoster</title>
</head>
```

<sub>**Nota**:Como comentamos [en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51967/vista-de-glyphicon-bootstrap/51973?noredirect=1#comment92002_51973) puede que sea fallo de tu codigo php que coge la ruta ya que `bootstrap.min.css` deberia contener `Glyphicons`</sub>

Comment: Pero el archivo `bootstrap.min.css` debería de incluir ya esos iconos, ¿no?

Comment: @kerunaru el problema puede ser de su codigo PHP, la ruta `"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"`  deberia valer tambien, si. [otro fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FzPEj/382/)

Comment: Y entonces... ¿De dónde sale el otro icono de correo, @ByGroxD? xD

Comment: No te va a leer, no le llega la notificacion por "@" si no es su publicacion o si no ha comentado. @kerunaru

Answer (score -1):

Deberias de crear una clase en CSS y agregarsela a tu elemento seria algo asi

```
#color{
color:#000;

}
```

Comment: No, la verdad no funciono asi

Comment: Se ve claramente que no es el mismo icono; cambiar el color del texto no funcionaría.